# What is the difference between Vavr `Try.of` vs `Try.run`

Tags: java, java-8, vavr

Wanted more info on difference between javaslang `Try.of()` and `Try.run()`

For example

`Try.of(() -> Integer.valueOf(str)).getOrElse(1)` compiles fine but
`Try.run(() -> Integer.valueOf(str)).getOrElse(1)` does not.

found in the package `javaslang.control` .
More info on the library:

- https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html
- https://www.vavr.io/

Comment: Where did you get these `Try` methods? They are not built into Java.

Comment: found it in the package `javaslang.control` . https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html

Comment: Provide that detail as an edit your Question rather than as a Comment

Comment: `of` accepts a `Supplier`, allowing you to specify a value which can be obtained via `get` after execution finished. `run` does *not* allow you to supply a value obtainable via `get`. If you're familiar with `ExecutorService`, it's similar to `submit(Runnable)` vs `sumbit(Callable)`

Comment: I think you're getting some confusion here because the library's old name, "javaslang", sounds so much like a standard library, "java.lang", that your question looks like a total mistake. I've edited your title and added a link to the project's homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Try.of()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html#of-javaslang.control.Try.CheckedSupplier-) takes a [`CheckedSupplier`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.CheckedSupplier.html), which has a `get()` method to "get a result".

[`Try.run()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html#run-javaslang.control.Try.CheckedRunnable-) takes a [`CheckedRunnable`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.CheckedRunnable.html), which has a `void run()` method to "perform side-effects".

Says so right there in the **documentation**.

The difference is the same as between a standard Java [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) *("represents a supplier of results")* and [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) *("execute code ... may take any action whatsoever")*. One is for *retrieving a value*, the other is for *executing some code*.

For examples of difference in use, see:

[*`andThenTry(CheckedConsumer<? super T> consumer)`*](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html#andThenTry-javaslang.control.Try.CheckedConsumer-)

```java
Try.of(() -> 100)
   .andThen(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

*[`andThenTry(CheckedRunnable runnable)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.6/javaslang/control/Try.html#andThenTry-javaslang.control.Try.CheckedRunnable-)*

```java
Try.run(A::methodRef)
   .andThen(B::methodRef)
   .andThen(C::methodRef);
```